# How to give acces to mysql database to another computer using same lan in ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ubuntu-16.04

my local ip is 192.168.1.30
I tried bind address= 192.168.1.30 in my.cnf and /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf .
i also tried bind address=0.0.0.0
But cannot access mysql from same lan.
Can you show me the proper way to access Mysql from another computer?
Can you also show the way to connect Mysql database to DBeaver from another computer?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: what exact error do you get when trying to connect?

Comment: ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '192.168.1.30:3306' (0)

Comment: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-set-up-mysql-for-remote-access-on-ubuntu-server-16-04/

Comment: I found this site before and tried to bind address 0.0.0.0 still doesnt work . Can you provide me the command to run mysql on another computer ? @ADyson

Comment: Please add the output of this command to your question: `ss -tulpen | grep 3306`.

Comment: previously it was "ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql' (1)".  Now its working properly after i commented "#Bind - address = 127.0.0.1" in my.cnf  and changed /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf  bind- address = 0.0.0.0. Thankyou @ADyson and digijay for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check the my.cnf in /etc/my.cnf or /etc/mysql/my.cnf
If there is any bind-address, then comment it with #
then in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf, add bind-address= 0.0.0.0
After it restart the mysql . Thats it